# How to visualize a blockingcollection

Tags: c#, multithreading, user-interface

I think i have some problems with logic right now.

I have used a blocking collection to make thread safe calls to other PCs. In general it looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private BlockingCollection<workUnit> workUnits = new BlockingCollection<workUnit>();

  public void EnQueue(workUnit item)
  {
    workUnits.Add(item);
  }

  private void DeQueue()
  {
    while (!stopFlag)
    {
      workUnit item = workUnits.Take();
      DoLongRunningDBStuff(workUnit);
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to visualize this to a user.

A user should see that

1. items are in Queue
2. item processing has started
3. result of processing (mainly passed/failed/exception)

And now I got some headache.

I was thinking to do the following:

Have a Grid to display the items to users.

1. If item is Enqueued add it to workunits and additionally to a list bound to the datagrid
2. If item is Dequeued (consumed) update the item in the list for the grid.

What makes the headache, is how to make this thread safe, and which parts are needed to be thread safe.

If I put something which takes time behind workUnit.Add I think it could be possible, that data gets mixed.

Would something like this be feasible?

1. If item is Enqueued add it to workunits and an additional BlockingCollection for UI
2. If item is Dequeued, make a tryget on 2. BlockingCollection and remove it there, update the status and attach it to second list again.

Would I need an additional lock aound 1 and 2? If so, wouldn't it block completly the add if waiting for Take?

Is there an easy solution or approach to visualize, what is going on?

Comment: That's a pretty heavy impedance mismatch, BlockingCollection is a class that's used in threaded code.  And UI is fundamentally thread-unsafe.  Also a serious risk of drastically slowing down the code.  Best not to do this, really.  It is an implementation detail a user should never have to worry about.

Comment: @Hans: Its not primally to show the internal implementation detail.

Comment: {always forget not to use enter herer) Think about the following usecase: Data is send to multiple PCs. This usually takes ~150 ms, but can also take up to 3s. In the former product there was a status line showing that data is send. Therfore users are used to and expect that a successor will also show informations, and that they have a screen where they can see, what was not succesfully send and can manually trigger a resend. The former is for user feedback that something is actually happening. The later for user interactions.

Comment: For example for adding the value that somebody can repeat failed jobs or that it can be looked up why something is failed (between machine is down, other side has a wrong version, both sides have changed data and they must confirm maually which one is correct and so on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try do it this way:

```
public class MyClass
{
  private BlockingCollection<workUnit> workUnits = new BlockingCollection<workUnit>();

  public void EnQueue(workUnit item)
  {
    workUnits.Add(item);
  }

  private void DeQueue()
  {
    while (!stopFlag)
    {
      workUnit item = workUnits.Take();
      item.SetState("Processing Started");
      try
      {
          DoLongRunningDBStuff(workUnit);
          item.SetState("Processing Successful");
      }
      catch
      {
          item.SetState("Processing Failed");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

in this example I would then make `workItem.SetState(...)` fire an *event* that will update UI for the particular item. However, because the event is raised in a non-UI thread, it will be the handler of the *event* (the form displaying the grid I would assume) that would need to post the update into the context of the UI thread (e.g. If you are using WinForms you would call the [Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method of the control displaying the data).

In another (preferred) suggestion I would do the following (if you can use the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) in .NET 4.0 and later):

```
public class MyClass
{
  public Task EnQueue(workUnit item)
  {
    // Schedule the work on the thread pool. 
    // If you need limited concurrency here, there are schedulers to enable this.
    return Task.Run(() => DoLongRunningDBStuff(item));
  }
}
```

And if you use .NET 4.5 you would be able to use the [await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156528.aspx) feature that would automatically synchronise the continuation of the task in the context of the UI thread. E.g. in the on the caller's side (assuming it is initiated on the UI thread) you would simply do the following:

```
private async void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = new workUnit();

    // TODO: Add item on UI here

    try
    {
        await myClass.EnQueue(item);

        // TODO: Update UI with success result here (no context synchronisation is needed here it is already in the UI context)
    }
    catch
    {
        // TODO: Update UI with error result here (no context synchronisation is needed here it is already in the UI context)
    }
}
```

In both examples you do not even need any locking, you simply need to have the updates posted to the correct context (and in the last example that is not even explicitly needed, the compiler takes care of it for you)

Comment: Hi, .net 4.0 or 4.5 would be fine, but the job is normally not initiallized by ui thread, but by a background thread. Therefore i think the "await" is not the solution. There are n-threads which can feed the task, but over the connection there should be only one thread at a time running. Therefore I have used the enqueue and dequeue with a synchron method dolongrunningstuff. (Okay there are multiple instances of the class, but only one instance per client). My problem is mainly also how to signalize that the thing is added. Isn't workUnits.Add(item); followed by item.SetState not threadsafe?

Comment: @Offler Whether the tasks get initiated by a background thread or the UI it self does not mean that the UI cant await the created tasks. Also, tasks does not have to be processed by n-threads. You could use one of the schedulers you find at the [official TPL examples](http://bit.ly/W4Bjm1) that will execute tasks on a single thread (and in the order it was created).